# how can i find tomorrow and yesterday with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I'm working with angularJS and I need to find the next and the previous day of a date.

I have the datepicker

```
<span data-ng-model="$parent.selected_date" is-open="opened" data-show-button-bar="false" datepicker-popup show-weeks="false" starting-day="1" language="locale" datepicker-options="datepickerConfig" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md text-center" data-tooltip="{{ 'Interface-UserWeek-Tooltip-Datepicker' | translate }}" data-ng-click="open($event)"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

I get the data from the ng-model ($parent.selected_date) and I need to get the day after and the day before (it's for implement my date-disabled). 
I have try to filter :

```
var day = $filter('date')($scope.$parent.selected_date, 'dd');
day++;
```

but it doesn't work the way I want when I'm at the end of a month (for example I don't want to find the 32 May but I want to have the 1st of June...)

Thank's

Comment: One way might be to try the moment.js library

Comment: +1 for moment.js, `moment().add('days', 1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bestest way would be to use moment.js . Bestest time library. [click here](http://momentjs.com/) to use moment.js.

You can simply use

```
  //previous day 

    moment.subtract('days',1);
 //next day  

     moment.add('days',1);
```

Comment: I'm in a project and I can't add library like I want :(

Comment: you can make a filter using moment.js to get next and previous date of a particular date